# Cannot open gdb folder from external drive using geopandas

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, geopandas

I am trying to open a `.gdb` folder from an external drive with `geopandas`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
data = gpd.read_file('/Volumes/SSD/data.gdb')
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
DriverError: '/Volumes/SSD/data.gdb' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

However, when I am trying the same on my local storage, `geopandas` can strangely read the folder just fine. Any ideas where this discrepancy in behavior might originate? I have observed this error with two different datasets so far.

---

**EDIT**:

I am on Mac OS 10.14.6.

I had a thought the files may have gotten corrupted when transferred to my external drive, but when copying back to my local drive I am able to open them just fine once again.

Comment: Are you on Linux? It is not a folder it is a geodatabase. Try specifying layer name `df = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Default.gdb', layer='polygon123')`

Comment: Forgot to say, I'm on Mac. Well, it's a file geodatabase, which *is* a folder. Specifying a layer doesn't help, but either way the strange thing would remain that I can read the exact same data on my local disk, but not from an external drive.

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the same issue. What I understand is that most of these geospatial datasets which are in a folder format, don't work if we copy and paste or manually create folders (strange behaviour). They only work with download or upload of the full folder. So I guess, the problem is how we set up the data in the external disk space (like Colab). Full folder without any new naming, copy or paste of files, straight download and upload worked for me (both in local Jupyter and Colab)